# spring-boot runs on port 8080 after mvn clean install

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am running a web application using spring boot.
when I run `./mvnw spring-boot:run` the application runs on the configured port in application.properties file which is 8083. but if I run `./mvnw clean install` then `./mvnw spring-boot:run`, the application runs on a the default port 8080.

Is there any clue?

this is my maven config file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13XOy_iu2zMQx7ohD5x0HS78PcEWjbIry/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you check the maven plugin configuration? Maybe maven install goal excludes properties files. Can you share pom.xml?

Comment: I attached the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the application.properties is not loaded because the resource folder is not configured in the pom.xml.

I added this to my pom.xml file :

```
    `<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>res</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>`
```